# Custom Range using CurrentRegion sets the cell index for the first column as -10?

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, range

This is a weird one as I didn't even know this was possible but hopefully, there is a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

```
ThisWorkbook.gRosterPermData.Address
```

Returns:
$L$1:$Z$6

Here is the weird bit

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, (14 + 1))).Address
```

Returns:
$X$1:$AK$6 (The same applies when i replace all '*blank*.' to ThisWorkbook.gRosterPermData.)

Therefore, after testing to actually get the range, I have to do this:

```
.Range(.Cells(1, -10), .Cells(6, 4)).Address
```

I'm so confused, I used CurrentRegion with "L1" as the input.

Any help or explanation would be greatly appreciated as this has not happened to any other range I have. Thanks.

Comment: If my assumptions as to the context (what the dot refers to) is correct,  and what you want is correct, just remove the dot (`.`) from before `Range` => `Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, (14 + 1))).Address`

Comment: Giving us isolated lines of code doesn't make for easy answers - there's a lot of guessing required around what you're actually doing...

Comment: Thanks Ron, you were right. I forgot to change my code when I copied it when splitting a formula into smaller ones; so the dot was no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little thrown by your opening syntax `ThisWorkbook.gRosterPermData.Address`.

However, `X1:AK6` is correct if the reference (for the . ) is the range $L$1:$Z$6 (named range `gRosterPermData`?). As you would be referencing relative to that range, not to the worksheet.

```
Public Sub GetDimensions()
    
    '$L$1:$Z$6
    With ActiveSheet.Range("gRosterPermData")
                           'row 1        'column 26
        Debug.Print .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, (14 + 1))).Address
        Debug.Print "row = " & .Cells(1, 2).row, " column = " & .Cells(.Rows.Count, (14 + 1)).Column
        Debug.Print "row = " & .Cells(.Rows.Count, (14 + 1)).row
    End With
      
End Sub
```

`with statement`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

As Ron alludes to in comments, it may be that you called on wrong object (I assumed within a With statement, and meant to use without the leading `.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes you are correct, it is always a simple fix isn't it. I wasn't having any problems because both my worksheet and custom range both start at "A1" for the other ones. That should have been the first red flag. This one doesn't. I copied code from a previous section and split it into separate formulas so forgot to remove the '.'. Thanks for the help!